# Launch a shortcut using batch file

Tags: shortcuts, batch-file, wildcards

Here's the problem.

I have a shortcut on roughly 260 computers located in the same folder as below;

"c:\documents and settings\all users\desktop\Remote agent **1234**.lnk"

The only thing that changes on the shortcut is the number. Is there a way to use a wildcard in a batch file to launch the shortcut instead of having to specify the full file name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use either [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) or [forfiles](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) for this task. Forfiles is more flexible, but it might not work properly on older versions of Windows.

#### For

From a command prompt:

```
for %a in ("C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\Remote agent *.lnk") do @start "" "%a"
```

In a batch file:

```
for %%a in ("C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\Remote agent *.lnk") do @start "" "%%a"
```

#### Forfiles

```
forfiles /P "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop" /M "Remote agent *.lnk" /C "cmd /C start \"\" @path"
```

Forfiles goes through all files in the path specified in `/P` that match the mask specified on `/M` and executes the command specified in `/C`. Here `@path` is the full path of the file.

Normally, we'd use the command `start "" "Remote Agent 1234.lnk"` to launch the shortcut. Since start is an internal command, we have to call it in a new shell (`cmd /C`). `\"\"` are just escaped double quotes, since the entire string is already quoted.

Comment: forfiles /P "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop" /M "Remote agent *.lnk" /C "cmd /C start \"\" @path" lists the files in the folder but does not open the shortcut.

Comment: That's odd. Echoing filenames is the default action, but the `/C` switch overrides that. Which version of Windows?

Comment: Xp Professional, its listing all file extensions as well which I assume isn't normal?

Comment: Doesn't look like its supported Dennis, again it just echos the files within the directory its run from. Thanks for the help thus far though!

Comment: I just found a source saying that some older versions of forfiles use `-` for switches instead of `/` (very atypical for Windows). Maybe this works: `forfiles -P"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop" -M"Remote agent *.lnk" -C"cmd /C start \"\" @path"`

Comment: Windows cannot find '@path'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again. To search for a file, click the Start button, and then click Search. Does something need to be put in place of " @path" ?

Comment: It seems that forfiles and XP don't mix well. I've added a for-based approach.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I'll let you know tomorrow when I'm in work if the For based approach works.

Comment: Working a charm Dennis, the FOR based approach seems to do the trick. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

According to HELP START program/command must NOT have double quotes. i.e. only
*for %%a in ("C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\Remote agent *.lnk") do @start /D"%%~dpa" %%~nxa*
works correctly!